# Deploying Telegram chatbot on Google Compute Engine and problem about webhook url setting

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I am deploying my Telegram chatbot on Google Compute Engine and getting stuck with the setting of the webhook url.

I have a config.ini to store the related information and I was trying to set with the url of the project:

```
[TELEGRAM]
ACCESS_TOKEN = {token}
WEBHOOK_URL = https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/setWebhook?url=https://{project-id}.appspot.com/hook
```

I set the firewall to 5000 in GCP. I copy & paste the link and it shows "{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}". But when I run my main.py (the chatbot script), the chatbot doesn't work. What the WEBHOOK_URL should be? What's the step to deploy - is it same as I used ngrok to copy & paste the link to confirm the hook then run the main.py?

When I run the main.py, it shows that I am in a development server and suggest that I should use a production WSGI. Is it a must to do so? Here's the log:

```
sys:1: TelegramDeprecationWarning: Old Handler API is deprecated - see https://git.io/fxJuV for details
* Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: on
2020-05-19 17:49:57,685 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-05-19 17:49:57,686 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Restarting with stat
sys:1: TelegramDeprecationWarning: Old Handler API is deprecated - see https://git.io/fxJuV for details
2020-05-19 17:49:57,969 - werkzeug - WARNING -  * Debugger is active!
2020-05-19 17:49:57,970 - werkzeug - INFO -  * Debugger PIN: 286-205-082
```

I don't think it's my main.py but just in case I put the related part here:

```
import configparser
import requests
import logging
import telegram
from flask import Flask, request
from telegram.ext import Dispatcher, MessageHandler, Filters, Updater, CommandHandler

# Load data from config.ini file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                level = logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Initial Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Initial bot by Telegram access token
bot = telegram.Bot(token = (config['TELEGRAM']['ACCESS_TOKEN']))

@app.route('/hook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook_handler():
    """Set route /hook with POST method will trigger this method."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        update = telegram.Update.de_json(request.get_json(force = True), bot)

        # Update dispatcher process that handler to process this message
        dispatcher.process_update(update)
    return 'ok', 200

def whatever_chatbot_function():
    .
    .
    .

dispatcher = Dispatcher(bot, None)

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_handler))
    .
    .
    .
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Running server
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Check the [transition to v12 guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0).  That's what the `TelegramDeprecationWarning` exception suggests.

You should be creating an instance of the `Updater` object, as per that guide.  Also there's a built in [webhook server](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#the-integrated-webhook-server) which avoids the requirement for Flask.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also asked and just got the reply from the python-telegram-bot admin, they said it's fine to use flask. I can't bother to modify the whole method at the moment. Still, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this:

```
def whatever_chatbot_function():
    updater = Updater(bot,use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_handler))
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting pure code as answers. The answer apparently does not meet the question